# Excel 2010 - Averaging columns data by different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My data includes several repeated measures (~4-5) for each participant and i want to be able to average all specific measures for each participant. 
for example, in the screenshot attached, i want to calculate the average for each of the measures (columns C-K, each column represent a different measure) for the first user (ID=38106100) the second user (ID=38212221) and so forth separately. That is, i want to calculate the average for each column using only the rows 2-5, than only rows 6-8, then 9-12, and so forth, without having to repeatedly for each participant ID (i have 200 participants).

Comment: Welcome.  Do you have any type of file or image sharing service where you can post your screen shot (just edit your question to include a link)?  That will enable someone to embed your screenshot in the question for you.

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the exact format, not attached a screenshot, so its a bit hard to guess.

Lets assume the following

```
Sheet1
A       B       C       D           E
name    date    unit_1  unit_2      unit_3
John    1-2-3   3       9           7
John    2-2-3   9       13          16
Maria   9-10-4  10      8           7
Maria   13-5-4  6       3           7
Maria   9-8-7   8       7           3
```

What you could do is create a second sheet.
- Create a column A holding the name of the current participant (or id, or whatever your sheet 1 column A is (or B?))
- Create a column B holding the first row containing the participant information of column A.
- Create a column C holding the last row containing the participant information of column A.
- Create columns D-L containing the averages.

Assuming you want to reserve row 1 for a header row, this example starts on row 2.

```
Row #2
A   = INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!A",B2)  
B   = IF(ROW()=2;2;C1+1)
C   = SUMPRODUCT(MAX((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!A",B2,":","A",B2+10))=A2)*(ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!A",B2,":","A",B2+10))))))
D   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!C",$B2,":","C",$C2)))
E   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!D",$B2,":","D",$C2)))
F   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!E",$B2,":","E",$C2)))
G   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!F",$B2,":","F",$C2)))
H   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!G",$B2,":","G",$C2)))
I   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!H",$B2,":","H",$C2)))
J   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!I",$B2,":","I",$C2)))
K   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!J",$B2,":","J",$C2)))
L   = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!K",$B2,":","K",$C2)))
```

Column B holds the first row (row 2) if this is the first row in sheet2, otherwise it will take the ending value of the row above and +1 it.
Column A gets the name belonging on that row from column A, row of column B2 from the sheet named 'Sheet1'.
Column C finds the first row having a different value in row A (Only checks up to 10 rows, if over 10 rows, stuff might break, adjust the number 10
if you need to service more rows.)
Columns D-L calculates the averages.
Columns D-L are basicly the same, so you could just drag the formula from D all the way to L.